how to reduce the width of top square root line
I have the following code:
$$\text{R}_\text{c} = \text{R}_\text{i} + \text{h} = \text{E}\sqrt{\!\biggl(\!\frac{9+3\sqrt{5}}{8} - \frac{1}{4\sin^2(36^\circ)}\!\biggr)} + \text{E}\sqrt{\!\biggl(\!\frac{6+2\sqrt{5}}{4} - \frac{1}{4\sin^2(36^\circ)}\!\biggr)}$$

$$= \text{E}\Biggl(\!\!\sqrt{\!\biggl(\!\frac{9+3\sqrt{5}}{8} - \frac{1}{4\sin^2(36^\circ)}\!\biggr)} + \sqrt{\!\biggl(\!\frac{6+2\sqrt{5}}{4} - \frac{1}{4\sin^2(36^\circ)}\!\biggr)}\!\!\!\Biggr)$$

Which outputs:

Is there a way to stop the top of the square root line from going past the parentheses when I reduce the amount of space between them?

you can use some \! after the closing )  but you already have three \! before it which makes the display look very cramped. (note that latex does not support $$ syntax, display math syntax is \[...\]

I'd not use \! at the beginning, maybe at the end. But you need to compensate for it with \,\, (a thin space is usually wanted when a parenthesis immediately follows a radical).
Some advice:

$$ should never be used in a LaTeX document;
\text is not the right tool and you need braces around the subscripts;
I'd add \, between \mathrm{E} and the radical;
the inner parentheses serve no purpose.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\mathrm{R}_{\mathrm{c}} = \mathrm{R}_{\mathrm{i}} + \mathrm{h} 
&= \mathrm{E}\,\sqrt{\biggl(\frac{9+3\sqrt{5}}{8} - \frac{1}{4\sin^2(36^\circ)}\biggr)\!}
 + \mathrm{E}\,\sqrt{\biggl(\frac{6+2\sqrt{5}}{4} - \frac{1}{4\sin^2(36^\circ)}\biggr)\!}
\\
&= \mathrm{E}\,\Biggl(\sqrt{\biggl(\frac{9+3\sqrt{5}}{8} - \frac{1}{4\sin^2(36^\circ)}\biggr)\!}
   + \sqrt{\biggl(\frac{6+2\sqrt{5}}{4} - \frac{1}{4\sin^2(36^\circ)}\biggr)\!}\,\,\Biggr)
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\mathrm{R}_{\mathrm{c}} = \mathrm{R}_{\mathrm{i}} + \mathrm{h} 
&= \mathrm{E}\,\sqrt{\frac{9+3\sqrt{5}}{8} - \frac{1}{4\sin^2(36^\circ)}\!}
 + \mathrm{E}\,\sqrt{\frac{6+2\sqrt{5}}{4} - \frac{1}{4\sin^2(36^\circ)}\!}
\\
&= \mathrm{E}\,\Biggl(\sqrt{\frac{9+3\sqrt{5}}{8} - \frac{1}{4\sin^2(36^\circ)}}
 + \sqrt{\frac{6+2\sqrt{5}}{4} - \frac{1}{4\sin^2(36^\circ)}}\,\,\Biggr)
\end{align*}

\end{document}

Note the \,\, also in the second display, bwcause a single one still makes the vinculum too near to the parenthesis.



If you're going to use upright characters everywhere in math mode, I think you can save yourself a lot of time and effort by switching to LuaLaTeX and loading the unicode-math package -- which loads amsmath automatically, by the way -- with the option math-style=upright. That way, you can avoid having to enter all those \text (better still: \mathrm) wrappers.

Do yourself a big favor and employ a two-row align* environment instead of two separate $$ ... $$ constructs. For sure, it'll make aligning the equations on the = symbols a lot easier. And, do consider using square brackets for the "outer" fences in the second row.

Last (and in my opinion least), you're free to create a rather cramped look by using \! (equivalent to \mkern-3mu) and \mkern-4.5mu directives in selected locations.
The following screenshot shows the cramped-looking result on top, followed by the non-cramped (dare I say "normal"?) result that does away with all negative-spacing commands.



\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math} 

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
R_c = R_i + h 
&= E\sqrt{\!\biggl(\frac{9+3\sqrt{5}}{8} 
   -\frac{1}{4\sin^2(36^\circ)}\biggr)\mkern-4.5mu} 
   +E\sqrt{\!\biggl(\frac{6+2\sqrt{5}}{4} 
   -\frac{1}{4\sin^2(36^\circ)}\biggr)\mkern-4.5mu}\\
&= E\Biggl[\!\sqrt{\!\biggl(\frac{9+3\sqrt{5}}{8} 
   -\frac{1}{4\sin^2(36^\circ)}\biggr)\mkern-4.5mu} 
   +\sqrt{\!\biggl(\frac{6+2\sqrt{5}}{4} 
   -\frac{1}{4\sin^2(36^\circ)}\biggr)\mkern-4.5mu}
    \,\Biggr]\\
\intertext{Same equations, but much less cramped:}
R_c = R_i + h 
&= E\sqrt{\biggl(\frac{9+3\sqrt{5}}{8} 
   -\frac{1}{4\sin^2(36^\circ)}\biggr)} 
   +E\sqrt{\biggl(\frac{6+2\sqrt{5}}{4} 
   -\frac{1}{4\sin^2(36^\circ)}\biggr)}\\
&= E\Biggl[\sqrt{\biggl(\frac{9+3\sqrt{5}}{8} 
   -\frac{1}{4\sin^2(36^\circ)}\biggr)} 
   +\sqrt{\biggl(\frac{6+2\sqrt{5}}{4} 
   -\frac{1}{4\sin^2(36^\circ)}\biggr)}
    \,\Biggr]
\end{align*}
\end{document}


I'm not sure I'd do this, but you just need to end the argument of the \sqrt with negative space, and then compensate with positive space outside.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}


\[
\mathrm{R}_{\mathrm{c}} = \mathrm{R}_{\mathrm{i}} + \mathrm{h} =
\mathrm{E}\sqrt{\!\biggl(\!\frac{9+3\sqrt{5}}{8} - \frac{1}{4\sin^2(36^\circ)}\!\biggr)} +
\mathrm{E}\sqrt{\!\biggl(\!\frac{6+2\sqrt{5}}{4} - \frac{1}{4\sin^2(36^\circ)}\!\biggr)}
\]

\[{}
  = \mathrm{E}\Biggl(\!\!\sqrt{\!\biggl(\!\frac{9+3\sqrt{5}}{8} -
    \frac{1}{4\sin^2(36^\circ)}\!\biggr)\!\!\!\!}\,\,\,\, +
  \sqrt{\!\biggl(\!\frac{6+2\sqrt{5}}{4} -
    \frac{1}{4\sin^2(36^\circ)}\!\biggr)\!\!\!\!\!}\,\,\Biggr)
  \]

\end{document}

